# Servlet not working on WebSphere 8.x

Tags: servlets, websphere-8

I have the following class...

```
package org.me.test
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/servlet")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.getWriter().write("Test Servlet");
    super.doGet(req, resp);
}
}
```

and the following Web.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0"> 
<servlet>
    <display-name>srv</display-name>
    <servlet-name>srv</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                 org.me.test.TestServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>srv</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/srv/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

but I get...

> Error 405: HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the 405 error because you are calling `super.doGet()` at the end of your `doGet()`. Try removing that line.

The default implementation of `doGet()` in the base class `HttpServlet` returns that 405 error. To support the GET operation, you must override `doGet()` *without* calling the parent implementation, otherwise it returns the same error intended to be displayed when there is no override.

Comment: That is a big Java dope let me refactor and try it out tomorrow.